# Why line passing through origin in the intersection of three planes is parallel to the planes?

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, vectors

- There are three planes $P_1, P_2$ and $P_3$ and they all pass through origin
  so it will have infinite solutions.
- The normal to these planes $n_1, n_2$ and $n_3$ are coplanar.
- The line passing though origin is perpendicular to normal vectors but
  is parallel to three planes.

Why is that line passing through origin parallel to the three planes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A line is parallel to a plane iff it is orthogonal to the normal vector of that plane. The three normal vectors are coplanar, which means that there is a line which is simultaneously orthogonal to all of them. That means this line is simultaneously parallel to each of the planes.

Comment: To check orthogonality we will take dot product of line and normal, but how does orthogonality inferring that line is parallel.

Comment: That's what "normal vector" means: it is orthogonal to the plane, so it is orthogonal to any line in the plane, so it is orthogonal to any line parallel to the plane.